# I need to know how to return an array of doubles from a function that has a 2D array of integers and a variable of type integer as parameters

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function, visual-studio-2012, average

I have a visual basic program that keeps track of the number of followers per month that each music band has. The user will specify how many bands exist and the number of months that each band has been followed(assume that months will be the same for all music bands). Therefore I have a dynamic 2d array which will store user input. Now I am struggling to calculate the average amount of followers that each band has, using a function of type double that returns an array of type double. This is what I have so far, could you please help me:

```
 Private Function ComputeAve(ByVal Info(,) As Integer, ByVal size As Integer) As Double()

    Dim sum(size) As Integer
    Dim ave() As Double
    Dim r, c As Integer
    For r = 1 To bands
        For c = 1 To months
            sum(r) = sum(r) + Info(r, c)
            ave(r) = sum(r) / months 
        Next c
    Next r

    Return ave

End Function
```

Comment: You shuold consider using a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), or a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which are favored when using VB.Net.

Comment: I have to agree with @Eminem.  2D arrays are usually not the best option, especially in VB.NET.  The VB.NET syntax for arrays is confusing enough without adding a second dimension into the mix.  In any case, it's not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish (as is typical with 2D arrays).  Perhaps some example input and output data would be helpful to demonstrate your intentions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see for your code not working is that you never actually create the `ave` array by setting the number of elemts it will have.

Assuming that info is an array with an element for each band and each month, you don't need the size, bands or months variables, that information is provided by the size of the array (which you can get with the GetUpperBound method).

I think the following does what you asked.

```
Private Function ComputeAve(ByVal Info(,) As Integer) As Double()
    Dim ave(Info.GetUpperBound(0)) As Double

    For r As Integer = 0 To Info.GetUpperBound(0)
        For c As Integer = 0 To Info.GetUpperBound(1)
            ave(r) += Info(r, c)
        Next c
        ave(r) /= Info.GetUpperBound(1) + 1
    Next r

    Return ave
End Function
```

Note that, as pointed out in the comments on your question, collections can be more useful than arrays, especially if you may need to add new items after you have created the array/collection.